# Browser Install with Bookmarks

Tags: windows-7, automation

Goal: Install firefox and chrome with a default set of bookmarks on Windows 7 x86. The immediate need is for freshly imaged machines to have bookmarks.

So I'm looking for an msi `/flag` or something to either import bookmarks for a file or import settings from IE.

Another possibility it seems is push installers/import actions from GPO on the domain. Seems like this might be best since if stuff changes in the future I can update as needed.

I'm open to other options as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this natively (that I know of), and is one of the reasons most big enterprises stick with IE.  It's easier to deploy and manage through native Windows tools, even if it does suck, as a browser.

When asked to do this in the past, I've said "no," and would advise the same, but in case you're not able to, you can script something up fairly easily to copy a previously created bookmarks file to the appropriate location for both browsers.  Install both, put the bookmarks in as you want, and then copy out the files to be deployed by a script or GPO after the browser is installed.

For Chrome, the location you seek is `...\Chrome\User Data\Default\`, and there's a file there called `bookmarks`, which contains the bookmarks.

For Firefox, it's `places.sqlite`, and the default location is `%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles`.  This file also holds the browsing history in Firefox, so that's something to be aware of.

I'd probably handle this with a GPP to be applied once, but you're just replacing one file with another, so there's any number of options available to do this; go with whatever you're more familiar and comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

The [Firefox CCK Wizard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/cck/) will create a custom extension for your site with your desired Firefox customizations. Deploy the extension that it creates along with Firefox onto end-user computers.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has a set of Group Policy Templates available for the Windows Group Policy Management Center that allow configuration of Chrome's settings. They package also includes Linux templates in the form of JSON config files ([Chrome Templates](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=187945)).  They have a link to the MSI installer in the [Chrome FAQ for administrators](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188447&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=1049071f4wose&cbrank=0), which can be used through GPO to install Chrome for all users on a machine (I assume it installs in the All Users profile folder to allow it's seamless auto updates). You cannot configure bookmarks directly with the GPO, although you can set the home page as well as a number of other settings.  It is possible, though, to use GPO to set IE's bookmarks and import them into Chrome.  You must launch IE on the new system first, and then launch Chrome and choose the Import IE Bookmarks option.

As for Firefox, to install it all you need is an MSI package.  As for configuring it using GPO, there are a few 3rd party projects that allow this, such as [FirefoxADM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/firefoxadm/).  I have not used any of these, so I cannot attest to how well these work.

Comment: Looks like firefox ADM hasn't been updated in over a year :( Cool idea but probably difficult to keep up to date with Mozilla's new(ish) chrome style release schedule.